# How to get ejs automatically re-render when firebase is updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ejs

I am building a webapp using Nodejs and generating the HTML page via EJS template. I am fine with the initial page load/refresh, it works as expected, it gets the data from firebase and populates. Later when the firebase collection is updated, re-rendering is not happening not able to see the newly added data in the webpage, but in the VSCode console i can see the listener publishing entire collection from firebase.

```
app.get('/feedback', (request, response) => {
  var appRef = firebase.database().ref().child('ApplicationList');
  var appList = {}, appNames = {};
  appRef.on('value', function(snap) {
    appList = snap.val();
    console.log('appList', appList);
    let keys = Object.keys(appList);
    for(let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
       appNames[keys[i]] = appList[keys[i]].longName;
    }
    console.log('Keys = ',keys);
    console.log('appNames = ',appNames);
    response.render('feedback.ejs', {
        pageTitle:'Feedback - Home',
        pageID: 'feedbackhome',
        pageName: 'Home',
        appNames
    });        
  });            
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to use websockets (e.g. [Socket.io](https://socket.io/)) in your NodeJS server to subscribe to these changes or move your Firebase listener to your client side logic (and on change call some endpoint in you NodeJS app if you needed to perform something on the server).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I wanted to do this in EJS because, i don't want to make a webapp with complex javascripting codes with createElement(). So decided to go with client side templating via handlebars.

```
function getAppNames(){
var appRef = firebase.database().ref().child('ApplicationList');
var allApps = {}, appNames =[];
let temp = {};
    appRef.on('value', function(snap) {
        allApps = {};
        appNames = [];
        allApps = snap.val();
        console.log('allApps', allApps);
        let keys = Object.keys(allApps);
        console.log('Keys = ',keys);
        for(let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
            temp = {};
            temp['shortName'] = allApps[keys[i]].shortName;
            temp['longName'] = allApps[keys[i]].longName;            
            appNames[i] = temp;
        }        
        appNames['appNames'] = appNames;
        console.log('appNames = ',JSON.stringify(appNames));        

        var source   = document.getElementById("sidebar-template").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);    
        $('.content-placeholder').html(template(appNames));
    });

}
```